# Thruway WebSocket connection on localhost

Tags: php, websocket, localhost, thruway, autobahnjs

Following the instructions from https://github.com/voryx/Thruway I am trying to set up a websocket server on localhost (Windows) which will only give me `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I started the server via [`> php vendor/voryx/thruway/Examples/SimpleClient.php`](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway/blob/master/Examples/SimpleClient.php) which gives me the following console output:

`2016-11-19T18:58:56.4982780 notice     [Thruway\Peer\Client 308] Changing PHP precision from 14 to 16
2016-11-19T18:58:56.5007740 info       [Thruway\Peer\Client 308] New client created
2016-11-19T18:58:56.5016600 info       [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 308] Starting Transport`

on the client side I am using the recommended example from https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js. Which should work - I could successfully connect to the testserver ws://demo.thruway.ws:9090.

Tested in latest Chrome on Windows 10 php7.

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's just a typo, but the example router is [SimpleWsRouter.php](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway/blob/master/Examples/SimpleWsRouter.php) not `SimpleClient.php`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think I got that wrong, would be great if there was a documentation on thruway and how it actually works.